# Log4j Jboss configuration

Tags: java, maven, log4j, jboss7.x

Im working on a web-app in Maven and JBOSS 7.1,

Iv had a look around but cant find any straight forward examples of how to set up log4j with maven and JBOSS 7.1.

Ideally i would like to be able to log to a different file on the server for each class that i will be capturing logs,

Can anybody help me out here?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I configured JBOSS 7.1 logger this way:

By default JBoss has several loggers (points where data comes in) and two appenders (points where data comes out) CONSOLE and FILE, defined in standalone.xml file in JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration directory.

In standalone.xml I created new appender in `<profile>` section:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FOO_BAR_FILE">
    <formatter>
        <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
    </formatter>
    <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="foo_bar_file.log"/>
    <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <append value="true"/>
</periodic-rotating-file-handler>
```

Added logger for specific class I needed to log:

```
<logger category="my.example.Foobar">
    <level name="INFO"/>
    <handlers>
        <handler name="FOO_BAR_FILE"/>
    </handlers>
</logger>
```

And my class Foobar:

```
public class Foobar {
    final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Foobar.class);

    public Foobar() {
        /* Log to foo_bar_file.log in jboss server log dir. */
        log.info("Foobar log example.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ...One question - the logger for specific class goes in standalone.xml also?

Comment: Yes, logger and appender configured in standalone.xml

Comment: I think that did work on the console anyway - now just trying to find where the file is saved!

Comment: just found it - in the JBOSS "log" folder - Thanks very much!

Comment: One final question - im trying to have my log files stored within my project folder sructure - am unable to do this so far in standalone.xml. Im trying to reference it as follows <file relative-to="projectname.logfolder" path="foo_bar_file.log"/> No errors come up but its not logging to that file.. When i use "/" instead of "." the server does not start up.

Comment: I dont know how to store log file to project directory, but I think there is some way to configure logger in WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml or log4j.xml file. You can find an example here: https://community.jboss.org/message/622568#622568